# multiple belongs_to relationships between two classes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, active-relation

I have a Transaction class. Each object of this class includes one issuing account, one sending account and one receiving account. Each of these is an instance of Account class. In my Transaction table, I have issuer_id, sender_id and receiver_id.

How should I specify relationship between Transaction and Account so that I can call

```
transaction.issuer
transaction.sender
transaction.receiver
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `:class_name` to specify the class name, when it can't be guessed from the association name:

```
class Transaction
  belongs_to :issuer,   :class_name => 'Account'
  belongs_to :sender,   :class_name => 'Account'
  belongs_to :receiver, :class_name => 'Account'
end

class Account
  has_many :issued_transactions,   :foreign_key => :issuer,   :class_name => 'Transaction'
  has_many :sent_transactions,     :foreign_key => :sender,   :class_name => 'Transaction'
  has_many :received_transactions, :foreign_key => :receiver, :class_name => 'Transaction'
end
```

You can read more in the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot meagar. I was puzzled by how I could specify the has_many/has_one in Account class vis-a-vis Transaction class. It turns out that I don't need to.

Comment: Not unless you intend to reference an account's transactions.

Comment: I was about to add that question. How should I call something like: acccount_one.transactions_as_issuer?

Comment: See the updated `:foreign_key` stuff; I wasn't thinking when I said use `:inverse_of`.

Comment: huhm, the has_many :foreign_key :classname specification doesn't seem to work for me. (I changed foreign_keys to :issuer_id etc. but it doesn't work either)

Comment: It is `:class_name`, not `:classname`

Comment: Thanks a bunch. In terms of user experience, SO can't be better than this :) What I learn from this is that belongs_to and has_one/many can be defined independently. Foreign keys must be stated explicitly when having multiple "roles".

Comment: Is this possible to do ```has_many :transactions```  and print out an aggregated list?